# How to lock selected nodes in TVirtualStringTree?

Tags: locking, selection, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a TVirtualStringTree with some checked nodes. After processing, some of those nodes are selected by the application for future use with double-click.

My problem is that after the application select some of those nodes, if any node is clicked or double clicked, the selection is lost. I need that only the application can make selection changes; and those selections must stay selected while still needed.

Is there someway to lock the selection to the user? I tried set the property

> `TreeOptions`.`MiscOptions`.`ReadOnly` ← True

but it cause errors on the component.

I looked at **SelectionOptions** property but could not find a subproperty to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After more and more tests I've found a property that solved my problem. 'SelectionLocked' isn't a public property and I didn't knew about it until now. If you set it to 'false' one can't select or desselect anything in the 'StringTreeView' until you set it back to true.